# AJAX call how to retrieve my javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I work with Rails 4 and basically I am searching a value on my html webpage traversing the DOM with jquery.
I store the value in a variable named **key** and I want to use this value to then make a request that would look like this :
`Record.find(id: key).name`

I perform an AJAX call and it works well (I checked it rendering status json ok). But now how can I use/retrieve the parameter **key** in my controller ?

I have a **User** and a **Record** model. In the `app/views/users`directory I have the partial `_form.html.erb` in which I am doing some javascript.

```js
var key = $('input#record_id').val();
```

And I want this variable to be available in the method **search** of my user controller, so that I can make a request with the parameter **key**.

So I am doing an AJAX call that looks like this :

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "/search",
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    value: key 
  },
  complete: function(){
    console.log('success');
  }
  });
```

And in my **config routes file** I wrote this route :

```
post '/search' => 'users#search'
```

In my User controller  I wrote the method like this :

```html
def search
  @record = Record.find(params[:key])
end
```

**Is @record available in my partial ? How can I print in my view the result of my request ?**

Can anyone tell me if I am doing right or wrong for my AJAX call ? Thanks for any help. If I forgot to mention any information you might need tell me and I'll edit my post.

I added a complete function in my AJAX call, that is supposed to show `success`if the AJAX call had been done and in my console log I have this message 'success' that appears

Comment: 404 error only if path is not correct which also means page is not existing of path entered. make sure that you are using correct path in ajax.

Comment: I restart my WebServer and it works well now. Weird. I've just edited my post would you have any idea on how to retrieve my **key** variable in my controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 404 not found the url must be wrong.

And to get the `param` key in your controller you must change `data` to `data: {key: key}` or if you use `data: {value: key}` then your action must change the name of the param like `@record = Record.find(params[:level])`

Basically, you are not using the right param name in your controller which is why the issue arises. Hope it helps.

To answer your second question:
@GDMN, you need to get your basics right! Every ajax has a success and failure callback.You could return json from your action which will be used by success callback and you could do whatever you want from there. Essentially in rails you might want to render a js file like this

Create a file named `search.js.erb` and use your javascript code in it like below

```
$('.some_id_or_class').html("<%= @record.name %>")
```

that will simply replace the element of that class with the value that is returned by `@record.name`

Comment: I did as you said and I use `data: {key: key}` and it seems to work. But how can I show in my views the result of the request `Record.find(id: key).name` that is in my controller ?

Comment: I created a file `search.js.erb` with the given javascript `$('div#result').html("<%= @record.name %>")` but nothing appears in my div....I wrote in my Ajax call `data: {key: key}` and in my controller `@record = Record.find(params[:key])` **is that right ?**

Comment: @GDMN, you need to debug, I can just give you pointers on how to solve your issue. You can accept the answer if it answered your primary question. You can post a new question for a new issue.

Comment: I am gonna accept the answer. About how to print the value there are no bug at all. I checked the consol it renders 'success' in my method it is supposed to render json with status 'ok' and if I check in the network there is a task with status ok rendered. So everything looks to work fine except nothing appears in my div. I'll post a new question....hop I'll see you there

Answer (score -1):

put the full url 
  url: "http://yoursite.domain/search",

Comment: You must explain why your solution would work. Also, when specifying a relative path like `/search` would essentially call the same url as you mentioned in your answer.